# Time in top bar with applications in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: indicator, time, top-bar

In my desktop, the top bar has the file through help menus for the current application, but I have to click the windows key to show the time etc on top. Is there a way to show that top bar with the time always, or show the current time alongside the application specific file-help menus?

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of the situation?

Comment: This is not default behavour. You must have an extension that hides the top bar. Disable all extensions, log out then back in, then re-enable them one by one. You will then see which extension is causing this.